# Get protein names corresponding to PDB ID

Tags: protein-structure

I have a list of about 4000 PDB IDs and would like to get the actual names of the proteins (e.g. lactate dehydrogenase, cytochrome c). I tried the batch header section at the [Protein Databank Download page](https://www.rcsb.org/downloads) but it refused to accept my PDB IDs in formats (xxxx or xxxx.pdb, individually or space-separated) that worked in an interactive search for the protein structure.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried writing a PyMol script?

Comment: Perhaps you could use ftp://ftp.wwpdb.org/pub/pdb/derived_data/index/entries.idx which contains HEADER and COMPOUND fields extracted from all PDB entries.

Comment: @Michael — Could you clarify please. A script tTo do what on what? And why in PyMol?

Comment: @marcin — Thanks, but the problem with the HEADER and COMPOUND fields is that they are such utter unparsable anarchy. I could write a script to get these fields from all my pdb files, but take for example 102L — I would get as HEADER "HYDROLASE(O-GLYCOSYL)" (useless) and as COMPOUND "HOW AMINO-ACID INSERTIONS ARE ALLOWED IN AN ALPHA-HELIX OF T4 LYSOZYME ENTEROBACTERIA PHAGE T4" where the name of the protein — Lysozyme — is buried. The prehistoric format of pdb files is the problem, but surely someone, somewhere has done something with them.

Comment: In which case, going from PDB to Uniprot using SIFTS [https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/docs/sifts/quick.html](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/docs/sifts/quick.html) is the best bet as the Uniprot entries will have all the synonyms you could have for.

Comment: @MatteoFerla Thanks. Will check that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use one of the [UniProt Protein APIs](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/proteins/api/doc/#!/proteins/getByCrossReference).

As you said you have your pdb entries in a text file line by line you can, like this `example.txt` containing:

```
1brr
4lzm
2dyi
```

Using the commandline, you can use a little script like this to download the name, if it is available for the given pdb entry.

```
while read line;
do 
 curl -X GET --header 'Accept:application/json' "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/proteins/api/proteins/pdb:$line" | 
 jq -r '.[].protein.recommendedName.fullName.value'  |
 sed "s/^/$line\t/" >> pdb_names.txt;
done < example.txt;
```

You need to have `curl`, `sed` and `jq` installed on your system.

This gives you following output in `pdb_names.txt`

```
1brr    Bacteriorhodopsin
4lzm    Endolysin
2dyi    Ribosome maturation factor RimM
```

---

Update

if you want to speed it up, you can run it with `parallel`.

```
parallel -j 4 'curl -X GET --header "Accept:application/json" "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/proteins/api/proteins/pdb:{}" |   jq -r ".[]. .protein.recommendedName.fullName.value"  |  sed "s/^/{}\t/" >> pdb_names_parallel.txt' :::: example.txt
```

With the `-j` option you call how many jobs should run in parallel. The limit of the UniProt API is 200 request per second per user.

---

Update 7. Nov 2020

To get another info beside the protein name, you need to know how the `JSON` response from UniProt looks like.

To get also the scientific name, you can run following command:

```
parallel -j 4 'curl -X GET --header "Accept:application/json" "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/proteins/api/proteins/pdb:{}" | jq -r ".[] | .protein.recommendedName.fullName.value + \" - \" + .organism.names[0].value"  |  sed "s/^/{}\t/" >> pdb_names_parallel.txt' :::: example.txt
```

As result you get this:

```
1brr    Bacteriorhodopsin - Halobacterium salinarum (strain ATCC 700922 / JCM 11081 / NRC-1)
4lzm    Endolysin - Enterobacteria phage T4
2dyi    Ribosome maturation factor RimM - Thermus thermophilus (strain HB8 / ATCC 27634 / DSM 579)
```

Comment: `sed` should also be available for you. You can install `jq` and `parallel` with `brew`

Comment: Many thanks. Got this running. Only problem is that on OS X the \t tab escape does not work (it is apparently non-standard) and none of the [answers here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145299/simple-sed-replacement-of-tabs-mysteriously-failing) worked for me. However it is easy enough to insert a tab after the four-character PDB ID programmatically.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6392271 for your tab problem.

Comment: Thanks again. I know it is bad form to ask supplementary questions, but could you possibly provide a link in your answer to the particular page in the API which describes the need to specify all of the four "dotted" terms. I went to https://www.ebi.ac.uk/proteins/api to try to find out how to construct a query to get the species (so I didn't have to ask) but must be looking in the wrong place. I can find an example XML for a protein under proteins/proteins that includes some of these terms, and various unpromising json thingies. NCBI provides intelligible APIs (or used to) — whereas EBI…

Comment: I've updated my answer. The dotted format is not a problem of the API. It is just how `jq` is getting the keys from the `JSON` formatted result. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters gives you a basic overview of how to use `jq`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can use `R`, have you tried with `biomaRt`? For example, using `2bhl` (my PhD lover :D)

```
library(biomaRt)
ensembl <- useMart("ensembl",dataset="hsapiens_gene_ensembl")

# get list of all available info
filters <- listFilters(ensembl)
attributes <- listAttributes(ensembl)

getBM(attributes=c('hgnc_symbol','ensembl_gene_id','entrezgene_id',
                'protein_id','description',"superfamily"), 
      filters = 'pdb', 
      values = "2bhl", 
      mart = ensembl)
```

Returns

```
hgnc_symbol ensembl_gene_id entrezgene_id protein_id description
1         G6PD ENSG00000160211          2539   ADO22353 glucose-6-phosphate dehydrogenase [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:4057]
2         G6PD ENSG00000160211          2539   CAA27309 glucose-6-phosphate dehydrogenase [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:4057]
3         G6PD ENSG00000160211          2539   AAA63175 glucose-6-phosphate dehydrogenase [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:4057]
4         G6PD ENSG00000160211          2539   AAA52500 glucose-6-phosphate dehydrogenase [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:4057]
5         G6PD ENSG00000160211          2539   AAA52501 glucose-6-phosphate dehydrogenase [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:4057]
6         G6PD ENSG00000160211          2539   CAA39089 glucose-6-phosphate dehydrogenase [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:4057]
7 ...
```

I am sure if you look at all the available filters and attributes, you can pinpoint the ID you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I can reproduce that, but only paint by numbers with R. How would I modify that to loop through a list of 4000 proteins and ensure the pdb ID was included in the output?

Comment: You can add `'pdb'` to the list of attributes. That will add a column with the pdb id. `c('pdb','hgnc_symbol',....),`

Comment: Ok. Get it. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure how your input file is (csv, vector, data.frame), but to run on multiple pdbs, you need to change your`values` (`values= c("2bhl","pdbID2","pdbID3",...)`)

Comment: My input is just a text file of filenames, one per line, generated from a unix ls command. I can convert it into a string of the type you suggest, although I wonder if there is any limit on the length of such strings. Referencing a text file would be preferable if it is possible.

Comment: I think the limit is 500 values x query, bu the newest versions of biomaRt should automatically split for you. I am not 100% sure, so you may want to double check. You can `ls *.pdb >> all_pdbs.txt` , use `all_pdb_list <- read.delim("./all_pdbs.txt")` to read `all_pdbs.txt` , and `gsub` to remove the extension from your entries (`gsub(".pdb","", all_pdb_list)`) .